# How can I run Powershell and run .exe file by Python code?

Tags: python, powershell

Currently, I am running an exe file (test.exe) by Powershell.
It requires an input file's name as an argument.
It means, I have to type `./test.exe input.txt` in Powershell command in order to run the file in powershell.

And now I want to automate this stuff by Python, but I couldn't found a clear way to do this.
As far as I figured out is that `import subprocess` and blah-blah is necessary but I am not that good into coding so can anybody tell me to make it?

> 'test.exe' file is located in C:\Users\KIM\Desktop\TEST and Powershell
>   is located in
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Powershell.exe', 'C:\Users\KIM\Desktop\Test\Test.exe', 'input.txt'])
```